# Google Cloud Storage:: Limitations

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have the following questions with regards to GCS:

1. Is there a limit on a number of blobs a bucket can contain?
2. I am using java client to mass create blobs in a multi-threaded application. Is there a limit on a number of blobs created per time unit? 
   Does Google Cloud Storage API flag requests as a potential DDoS attack when a particular threshold is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas) page has some documentation about this. Specifically:

1. No, there is no limit on the number of objects in a bucket.
2. From the docs page:

   > There is no limit to writes across multiple objects. Buckets initially
   >   support roughly 1000 writes per second and then scale as needed.